# Web Scraping Automation programs

Tags: xml-parsing, web-scraping, screen-scraping

This may be off topic but if anyone can help or point me in the right direction.....or the correct place to put this question?

Can anyone suggest a good Automated Web Scraping program for use on a windows machine?
I would like to be able to automate the process and set it to be able to "scrape" the site every 5 mins or so and have the resulting xml exported to another website or database?

Comment: What type of content are you trying to web scrape? Is it simple static content? XPath or a library with CSS selectors, a web client, and an HTML parser would do. Is it dynamic content? Then you'll need some way to let the JavaScript do what it wants and then scrape it with said tools. It really just depends on how the content is presented on the page. I think you just need some clarification on this.

Comment: Hi Jaxrtech thanks for the reply, atm im using jsoup in a android app to scrape the pages, it is just simple content i.e Tables, but it is taking some time to do (around 10sec) for all the pages so I was starting to think about doing the parsing on a computer and then uploading all the data (with its structure intact)  to a webpage for scraping all in one go by jsoup from my app? perhaps this is not the best way to go about it but I am only really starting to toy with the idea and speed up the process. Do you think  what im asking can be done? or a better way to get all the data in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual process is taking too long, those 10 seconds or more likely to being the network latency rather than actual parsing and scraping its self. If that is the case, you probably want to have them executing in parallel rather than sequentially if you have not already done so.

It would help if you had a more specific issue as there is several ways about going about this. You could have it still parsing on the phone. If that is too problematic for whatever reason, in my opinion, I would instead build a separate HTTP REST server for the phone client to have it interact with to get the data it requires.

There is many ways about going about this, and these are simply recommendations.